# The type or namespace name 'DocumentFormat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I use VS 2010 in windows 7.
When I tried to build my .Net project.
There shows the compiling error: `The type or namespace name 'DocumentFormat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

code:

```
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
using Xdr = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet;
```

I have installed Open XML SDK 2.5 but the same error still exist.

Comment: Please add some code to show exactly where are you getting the error.

Comment: @Voodoo I have added

Comment: Actually, these are the namespaces, so you cant just use like this.

Comment: @Voodoo We use CI in GitLab to develop our project in teamwork, the code was written by others and went through testing, so the code has no problem, it's environmental problem of my IDE.

Comment: I have tested it, it works well. Therefore, I have two suggestions. First, you can uninstall the related nuget package or dll and reinstall nuget package ->DocumentFormat.OpenXml. Second, if the first doesn't work, I suggest that you can install the latest vs version (vs2017 or vs2019).